# delete rows in excel using python

Tags: python, xlwt

If the third column contains the value N, then I need to be able to delete the entire row.

I'm trying to automate this using python and xlwt, but am not quite sure where to start.

It would be grateful if somebody can help through a small code snippet.

Comment: I know you want xlwt.. I achieve this using pandas: `DataFrame.dropna(self, axis=1, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None)` See : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616563/in-python-removing-rows-from-a-excel-file-using-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils

Answer (score 0):

`xlwt` does not provide directly this kind of functionality.

One solution is to read from one .xls and write to a new one.

You can find here all funcionalities from `xlwt` [api](http://xlwt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)